# Strange issue when installing Enterprise application

Tags: ios, enterprise-distribution

I'm encountering a strange issue on certain iPads when I try to test my build. On most devices the installation works like a charm, but I've noticed the following on a couple devices:

I get the prompt to install ".. would like to install MyApp". After hitting Install, nothing happens. There's no indication of what the error is afterward.

As mentioned, the installation works perfectly on other devices.

This is occurring on iOS 8.0 and iOS 8.0.1

Any ideas if this is related to a configuration on the device?

Comment: Does this happen multiple times to the same device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably the iOS enterprise install bug. If the devices previously had the app in iOS 7 and were then upgraded to iOS 8, then the device will incorrectly cache the Bundle ID and refuse to install updates to the app or even reinstall it after it has been deleted from the device.

Currently, the only work-around is to append some extra characters to the Bundle ID in the manifest.plist file that accompanies the IPA on the install page. This will trick the device into thinking it's a new app and downloading it. Once the app actually installs, it will use the correct Bungle ID from the app and replace the existing one.

Comment: <snicker> "Bungle ID" ?  Well played.  :-)   I did not know about that bug, but since iOS 8.0 and 8.0.1 were mentioned, I wondered if it might be one.  Since 8.1.x is not mentioned, does that mean it is fixed in those versions?

Comment: I do not believe it has been fixed yet.

Comment: This actually makes sense. I did notice that installing from our pre-production distro page did work. The plist on that server contains a pre-prod identifier. I'll give this solution a try shortly.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try an install after you've attached a device to a Mac and start capturing its console output.  The iOS may be outputting errors there.

I assume your app size is under the cellular transfer limit.

Comment: Our company hasn't provided an upgrade to the latest XCode/iTunes which is preventing me from capturing logs for the devices in question with 8.0.1